# What's the error in the following PHP code?

Tags: php, debugging, dreamweaver, heredoc

I'm testing the following code. I'm using PHP heredoc but I'm getting an error from dreamweaver. If I write it manually, it works. If I copy paste it doesn't work. Why is that?

```
<?php

$e=<<<EOP
whoever
EOP;

$el=<<<EOG
whatever
EOG; 
?>
```

[image]

Comment: there should be an added return under the last `EOG;` and there is also a space after the last one, remove it

Comment: @Fred-ii-Can't follow you there.

Comment: You code does not have syntax error. The version of your Dreamweaver is old. Update it to latest one.

Comment: I'd say most likely there are invisible differences between what you paste and what you type. Different type of line break or maybe even some UTF8 issue.

Comment: @Fred-ii- You're right the problem was the space after EOG; !!! Can you add what you wrote as an answer?

Comment: @arkascha there is a space in OP's last delimiter; highlight it and see.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I saw that, sure. Because of your initial comment. Is that an issue? Didn't know that. Why? And why your remark about the required additional "return", what do you mean by that?

Comment: @arkascha well in my past experiences, not having a return after a delimiter didn't work, but it seems not always the case.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I confirm the behavior. Looks like a bug in the heredoc parser to me. Strange... Great spotting you show!

Comment: @arkascha In having highlighted OP's code is when I noticed the space. *Cheers*

Comment: Interesting, the documentation shows this: `WARNING: It is very important to note that the line with the closing identifier must contain no other characters, except a semicolon (;). ...`

Comment: Why the downvotes? Is it banned to ask about bugs on this site?

Comment: @whatever Note sure. Might be related to not having read the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a space after your last closing identifier.

```
<?php

$e=<<<EOP
whoever
EOP;

$el=<<<EOG
whatever
EOG; 
    ^ right there
?>
```

- **It needs to be removed.**

As per documentation http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

> **Warning**
>   It is very important to note that the line with the closing identifier must contain no other characters, except a semicolon (;). That means especially that the identifier may not be indented, and there may not be any spaces or tabs before or after the semicolon. It's also important to realize that the first character before the closing identifier must be a newline as defined by the local operating system. This is \n on UNIX systems, including Mac OS X. The closing delimiter must also be followed by a newline.

Comment: It's really a weird bug.

Comment: @whatever If Dreamweaver is adding spaces somewhere, that would be something to look into. Unfortunately, I don't work in Dreamweaver.

Comment: Is there a better alternative to dreamweaver?

Comment: @whatever  you can use `sublime text 3`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Not sure if you really mean the "unfortunately" :-)

Comment: @arkascha If I was working with versions past version 1.0 I'd of probably been able to figure out why, if DW is adding spaces. I haven't worked in DW since their 1st/2nd release.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sure, though that was not what I meant :-)

Comment: @whatever As Hassan pointed out. I myself hard code using Notepad++ but there are other code editors out there that are pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

try to remove a space after "EOG;"

```
<?php

$el=<<<EOG
whatever
EOG;

?>
```

Comment: Well, this has been clearly pointed out before by others. However if you still post this answer, you should at least remove that space yourself after using copy&paste to copy the code...